# Proof of Lemma 19.24 in van der Vaart: step by step proof

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

*In what follows I will sketch the proof of Lemma 19.24 in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics". I'm having troubles in understanding which objects are random and which are not. Thanks in advance for any hint you could give me. The proof is adapted to the case in which we have a parametric class of functions and the randomness is caused by the estimate of the parameter (as in the case of $Z$-estimator). I have enumerate the questions with capital letters so that it will be easier to answer.*

Consider the i.i.d. random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. $X_i:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ is defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ with probability distribution $P$ $\forall i$. Let $f_{\theta}:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of functions $f_{\theta}$. Let $\hat{\theta}_n$ be an estimate of $\theta$ depending on $Y_n:=(X_1,...,X_n)$. Let $\theta_0 \in \Theta$.

Let $\mathbb{P}_nf_{\theta}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)$, $Pf_\theta:=\int_{\mathcal{X}}f_\theta(x)dP(x)$, $\mathbb{G}_nf_\theta:=\sqrt{n}(\mathbb{P}_nf-Pf)$, $\mathbb{G}_n:\Omega \rightarrow l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ (stochastic process).

---

Assume

(1) $\mathcal{F}$ is P-Donsker, i.e. $\mathbb{G}_n$ weakly converges to a tight  and zero-mean gaussian stochastic process $G_P$ in $l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F})$.

**(A)** Using definitions of expectations is this translated as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}(g(\mathbb{G}_n(\omega)))d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int_{\Omega}(g(\mathbb{G}_P(\omega)))d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ $\forall g:l^\infty(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded?  Which respect to which metric is continuity checked?

(2) $\int_{\mathcal{X}}(f_{\hat{\theta}_n}(x)-f_{\theta_0}(x))^2dP(x)\rightarrow_p0$, i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t.}\int_{\mathcal{X}}(f_{\hat{\theta}_n(Y_n(\omega))}(x)-f_{\theta_0}(x))^2dP>\epsilon\})=0$

(3) $f_{\theta_0}\in L_2(P)$

**(B)** Where do I use (3) in the proof?

Then $\mathbb{G}_n(f_{\hat{\theta}_n}-f_{\theta_0})\rightarrow_p 0$.

**(C)** Should this be interpreted as $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \mathbb{G}_n(f_{\hat{\theta}_n(Y_n(\omega))}(X_i(\omega))-f_{\theta_0}(X_i(\omega)))>\epsilon\})=0$?

This implies that  $\mathbb{G}_nf_{\hat{\theta}_n}\rightarrow_d \mathbb{G}_Pf_{\theta_0}$.

**(D)** Should this be interpreted as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} h(\mathbb{G}_n f_{\hat{\theta}_n(Y_n(\omega))}(X_i(\omega)))d\mathbb{P}= \int_{\Omega} h(\mathbb{G}_P f_{\theta_0}(X_i(\omega)))d\mathbb{P}$ $\forall h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded?

---

**Sketch proof:**

(i) Assume $f_{\theta_0}\in \mathcal{F}$.  Then (2) implies $f_{\hat{\theta}_n}\rightarrow_p f_{\theta_0}$ in the metric space $(\mathcal{F}, L_2(P))$.

(ii) Consider a function $g:l^\infty(\mathcal{F})\times \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(z,f)=z(f)-z(f_{\theta_0})$. We can show this function is continuous with respect to the product metric.

**(E)** Which are the two metric involved in the product? one should be $L_2(P)$  for $\mathcal{F}$. Which is the metric for $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$?

(iii) By (1)+(i) we have $(\mathbb{G}_n,f_{\hat{\theta}_n})\rightarrow_d (\mathbb{G}_p, f_{\theta_0})$ in $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})\times \mathcal{F}$.

**(F)** Should this be interpreted as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} h(\mathbb{G}_n(\omega), f_{\hat{\theta}_n(Y_n(\omega))})d\mathbb{P}= \int_{\Omega} h(\mathbb{G}_P(\omega), f_{\theta_0})d\mathbb{P}$ $\forall h:l^\infty(\mathcal{F})\times \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded? Which respect to which metric is continuity checked? It should be the product metric of question (E) I think.

(iv) By lemma 18.15 the sample paths of $\mathbb{G}_P$ are uniformly continuous with respect to the variance semimetric $\rho$ and we are done.

**(G)** Is $\rho$ the metric I should consider for $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ in the product metric of steps (ii) and (iii)?